# Plain text comments

Tags: comments, 8

In Drupal 8, can I remove the subject field from comments and only have a single plain text box?

My goal is to set up something like a ticket tracking system. I will have a the Issue node. But I'd like to have a repeating text field that any authenticated user can *add* to. I'd like a user to report a problem. For this notes piece, it looked like comments would be the most logical. That is I need the Note to be saved for historical purposes and I don't want people to edit or change the initial issue.

Or, should I use another content type (let's call it Note) with an Entity Reference back to the related Issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Probably yes. Did you meant to ask "how"? Also, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Thanks. I've expanded my question above trying to explain the goal. I'm looking for comments but without the subject line. I only want a single text field, username, and date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See admin > structure > comment types then click manage fields. Configure from manage form display.